# snap-store and gnome-software taking too much ram

Tags: snap, ram, gnome-software

[image: Screenshot]

I didn't even opened ubuntu-software store when this showed up. Is there a way I can avoid this from happening? Also, if I remove the snap-store package will I'll be able to install snap apps using the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely uninstall the Snap Store app, and if you do you will still be able to install snap apps from the terminal with `sudo snap install package-name` and also to manage installed snap apps from the terminal.

Your RAM usage for the snap-store and gnome-software seems unusually high. My RAM usage for gnome-software is 1.4 MiB even if the app isn't open. My RAM usage for snap-store is 0 if the app isn't open, and 4.0 KiB if the Snap Store is open. To release memory from the cache run `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid the high ram-usage? Also, I installed snapd and all my apps I installed through snap disappered

Comment: To release memory from the cache run `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.